# How to have script run the same process for multiple URLS with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

What i'm trying to do is have selenium do the same process on different urls. What my script does is it goes to a url ( which is a property auction site ) and monitors the price and alerts me via text (twilio) of any changes. Right now it works for 1 property at a time. I now need it to do the same process to multiple urls at the same time.

Here is all my code:

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import ssl
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
urls = [
    'https://www.hubzu.com/property/0007190806526-3925-E-Landis-Ave-Vineland-NJ-08361',
    'https://www.hubzu.com/property/0007192328826-100-Melissa-Ln-Headland-AL-36345'
]
while True:
    browser.get(('https://www.hubzu.com/property/9007091467618-3632-Stokes-Drive-Sarasota-FL-34232'))# Live Auction Bid URL
    time.sleep(2)
    address = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').find('span', {'class':'h1'}).text
    propertyprice = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid')
    currentBidText = propertyprice.text
    try:                                
        WebDriverWait(browser, 90000).until_not(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-bid'), currentBidText)
            )
    finally:
        print("+++ Send notifications.")
        account_sid = "***"
        auth_token = "***"
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

        PhoneNumber1 = "***"
        PhoneNumber2 = "***"
        print("+ Send notifications to: ", PhoneNumber1, " and ", PhoneNumber2)

        sendTo1 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber1 + "\"}"
        print("+ sendTo1: ", sendTo1)
        sendTo2 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber2 + "\"}"
        print("+ sendTo2: ", sendTo2)

        notify_service_sid = "***"
        notification = client.notify.services(notify_service_sid).notifications.create(
                body='There has been a change at: '+address,
                to_binding=[sendTo1, sendTo2]
            )

        print("+ Notification SID: ", notification.sid)

        print("+++ Exit.")
    continue
```

Comment: Have a look at [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)

Comment: i'd have to re-write arguably everything. no?

Comment: Just loop through the list of URLs... what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just loop through a the list of desired URLs provided you want to do literally the same thing on each.

```
urlList = ["your first URL here", "your second URL here", ...]

for url in urlList

    # your setup code here

    browser.get(url)

    # all the other stuff you want to do here
```

If you really really want to do multiple loops at the same time just launch the program several times, maybe passing the URL in as a command line argument (remove the URL loop), and let your machine handle it.